# flutter: how to make reusable gridView widget

Tags: flutter, listview, gridview, widget

I have a gridview widget but I want to make it re usable so I can reuse it in many places without writing it again and again.
I have write it but I am facing one issue,

here is the widget i have written,

```
class GridViewSelection extends StatelessWidget {
  GridViewSelection(
      {super.key,
      required this.menuList,
      required this.onTap,
      this.imageList,
      this.nameList,});

  VoidCallback onTap;
  int menuList;
  List? imageList;
  List? nameList;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: GridView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3, mainAxisSpacing: 10, crossAxisSpacing: 10),
            itemCount: menuList,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: onTap,
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            imageList![index],
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            nameList![index],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: AppTheme.colors.greyFontColor),
                          ),
                        ]),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

the issue i am facing is, I have a list in which i have defined the name and image for the grid view. the problem is, how will i use that list. this is how I am reusing the widget but it throws an error.

```
GridViewSelection(
   menuList: oldMenu.length, 
   imageList: oldMenu, 
   nameList: oldMenu,
      onTap: (){}),
```

I can not use it like this but its says that **[index]** is not defined for the list.

```
GridViewSelection(
   menuList: oldMenu.length, 
   imageList: oldMenu[index].image, 
   nameList: oldMenu[index].name,
      onTap: (){}),
```

any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `GridViewSelection` requires `List?` for names and images but you are trying to supply one element. In order to fix this, you will have to extract a list of `name` and `image` each, from your list `oldMenu` and then supply it to the constructor.

Revised code:

```
GridViewSelection(
   menuList: oldMenu.length, 
   imageList: oldMenu.map((element) => element.image).toList(), 
   nameList: oldMenu.map((element) => element.name).toList(),
      onTap: (){}),
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you sooo much, this is exactly what i was looking for. just one more question,
how do I get the **index** value of a list using **onTap** function, if you see in the gridview builder, I have a void onTap function, how can I pass **list index** throught that. so that when I use the snippet, and onTap I get that exact tapped value in a string.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please accept this answer if it worked for you. Also, post a new question for list index, along with relevant information as per SO rules and we will be happy to help. Thanks!

Comment: i have posted the same question in more detail. can you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're returning your widget inside itemBuilder of a list to be given the index to use it.